# Persisted objects overwrite the last record instead of creating a new one with Spring MVC, Google App Engine, JDO3

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-mvc, jdo

I'm using Spring MVC 3.1.2 with Google App Engine. I have a problem with persisting objects in the data store using JDO3. The weird problem is that whenever I persist objects (during  a short period of time) the last added object doesn't get persisted in a new record it just overwrites the last record keeping the same id (the id of the last record). Here are  the files that could be concerned.

User.java

```
@Component
@PersistenceCapable
public class User {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Persistent
    private String firstName;
    @Persistent
    private String lastName;
    @Persistent
    private String email;
    @Persistent
    private String password;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }   

}
```

UserDaoImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    private static PersistenceManager pm;

    @Override
    public void add(User user) {

        if (pm == null || pm.isClosed()) {
            pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        }

        try {

        pm.makePersistent(user);    
        } finally {

        pm.close();

        }
    }

}
```

PMF.java

```
public final class PMF {
    private static final PersistenceManagerFactory pmfInstance =
        JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

    private PMF() {}

    public static PersistenceManagerFactory get() {
        return pmfInstance;
    }
}
```

UserController.java

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    User user;


    @RequestMapping(value="/adduser", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    String adduser(){

        return "adduser";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/adduser.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    String saveUserr(@RequestParam String firstname,@RequestParam String lastname,   @RequestParam String email, @RequestParam String password){


        this.user.setFirstName(firstname);
        this.user.setLastName(lastname);
        this.user.setEmail(email);
        this.user.setPassword(password);
        userService.add(user);//this invokes the UseDaoImpl add(user)

    }
}
```

jdoconfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig_3_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig_3_0.xsd">

   <persistence-manager-factory name="transactions-optional">
       <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass"
           value="org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory"/>
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.RetainValues" value="true"/>
       <property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns" value="true"/>
       <property name="datanucleus.appengine.singletonPMFForName" value="true"/>
   </persistence-manager-factory>
</jdoconfig>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I feel is you are not initializing the User Object, instead of Autowired annotation try the following code.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/adduser.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
String saveUser(@RequestParam String firstname,@RequestParam String lastname,   @RequestParam String email, @RequestParam String password){
    User user = new User();
    user.setFirstName(firstname);
    user.setLastName(lastname);
    user.setEmail(email);
    user.setPassword(password);
    userService.add(user);//this invokes the UseDaoImpl add(user)
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but I'm wondering is there a way to keep the Autowired annotation and make it create a new instance every time the saveUser method is invoked ? does it have anything to do with the scope of the bean ?

Comment: Well Autowired annotation is used usually to locate the DaoClassImpl in our xml, here you don't need it because you might have bean in other package which you can directly instantiate without autowiring it.